# Need help understanding the span of the following vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & -2 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I am told that the span of vectors equal $R^m$ where $m$ is the rows which has a pivot in it.  So when describing the span of the above vectors, is it correct it saying that they don't span $R^3$ but only span $R^2$?.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please format your question using MathJax? See for example https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once your matrix is in the pivot form, that is one way to calculate the dimension of the row space. In this case yes you have 2 pivots so the dimension would be 2. I would be careful in saying they span $R^2$. Since though $R^2$ and $\{(x,y,0),x\in R, y\in R\}$ are similar, they are not exactly the same. This is because from your perspective you would call $\{(x,y,0),x\in R, y\in R\}$ and $\{(x,0,y),x\in R, y\in R\}$ both $R^2$, but they are in fact different planes in $R^3$

Comment: Alright thanks.  I am asked to describe the span, so what would i do.

Comment: @God the span of the row vectors or the column vectors? And you are referring to the 3 by 3 matrix right?

Comment: im referring to the 3x3  matrix but it is just asking me for the "span".  Does mention columns or row.

Comment: @God That is ambiguous, since a span is used for a set of vectors, and we need to define which set of vectors we are using, either the row vectors or the column vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Since your vectors are linearly dependent but two of them are linearly independent, they will span a two dimensional subspace of $R^3$

The span is not necessarily $R^2$ but it is a plane passing through the origin.